# Search for a string entered in a TextBox of a UserForm over range of cells and return column value of the row

Tags: excel, vba, string, search

I have data in columns A, B, C, D. I have a UserForm where I will enter a string to search in a TextBox.

When I click a search button on the UserForm, it should search for the entered string in columns A, B and C. In whichever row the string is found, it should display the column D value of that row in a ListBox.

Example:
[image]

From above example when I search for string "Bag" my ListBox should have following values:  return1, return2, return3

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    row_num = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    searchString = srchtxt.value
    Me.ListBox2.Clear
    If srchtxt.value Like "*[!.A-Za-z_ ]*" Or (IsNumeric(srchtxt.value) = True) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Do
            DoEvents
            row_num = row_num + 1
            item_num = SHEET17.Range("A" & row_num)
            item_num1 = SHEET17.Range("B" & row_num)
            item_num2 = SHEET17.Range("C" & row_num)
            item_desc = SHEET17.Range("D" & row_num)
            If InStr(1, item_num, searchString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Me.ListBox2.AddItem (item_desc)
            ElseIf InStr(1, item_num1, searchString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Me.ListBox2.AddItem (item_desc)
            ElseIf InStr(1, item_num2, searchString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Me.ListBox2.AddItem (item_desc)
            End If
        Loop Until row_num = 10000
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Range.Find` yet?

Comment: Hi, im completely new to VBA, plz help me with the code. it would really be of great help!

Comment: [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) should be helpful.

Comment: Have you actually tried *anything* yet or do you just want us to write your code for you?

Comment: i have the code written, bt my code does search columnA and then it searches ColumnB and then ColumnC but since i have lot of rows around 10,000 it is really time consuming i would post my code here in sometime.

Comment: If you don't like `Find`, then read your data into an array and loop the array.

Comment: So it is supposed to search column by column *or* row by row? I mean, if you'd look for 'Bag', do you want to return 'return2' or any of the top three values in column D?

Comment: Hi All, I posted my code in question itslef, may be it will be helpful if u go through....Kindly help me

Comment: Hi JvdV, when i search for Bag my listbox should have following values:  return1,return2,return3. If it searches row by row it will be good. so that it can return column D value when a string is found in any of columnA or ColumnB or ColumnC

Comment: Hi BigBen, if i loop array, how to return column D value into my Listbox? Help me with that

Comment: As Mr.BigBen suggested, try to use range.find. For example, you create a range variable for column D. Something like `set rg = range("D2",range("D2").end(xldown))`. Then you loop within rg : `for each cell in rg` ... create a range for column A to C where the row is the looped cell row `set rgS = range(cell.offset(0,-3),cell.offset(0,-1))`. Now you check if the string in the textbox is found within rgS ... `set c = rgS.find(srchtxt.value,lookat:=xlpart)` ... if found then add the item to the listbox ---> `if not c is nothing then ListBox2.AddItem cell.value` ... `next cell`.

Comment: Another way, create a helper column (whatever column which is not used) where the value is the concatenation of each row of column A to C. Filter this helper column with the criteria from the textbox value. Then add each visible cell value within D2 to whatever row as the item of the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Find and FindNext

update - unique values sorted

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim sSearch As String, sAddr As String
    Dim rngFound As Range, rngSearch As Range
   
    Dim arList As Object, i As Long, colD As String
    Set arList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    ' check user entry
    sSearch = Trim(srchTxt.Value)
    If Len(sSearch) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No search text entered", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' column A and C
    With Sheet17
         Set rngSearch = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A:C")).Offset(1) ' exclude header
    End With
    
    ' search for text and fill arraylist with unique col D value
    Me.ListBox2.Clear
    
    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(sSearch, _
           LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        sAddr = rngFound.Address
        Do
            colD = Trim(rngFound.Offset(0, 4 - rngFound.Column)) ' Col D
            If Not arList.contains(colD) Then arList.Add colD
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> sAddr
    End If
    
    
    ' update listbox with sorted values
    arList.Sort
    For i = 1 To arList.Count
       ListBox2.AddItem arList(i - 1)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG thank u sooooo much CDP1802 for ur help on this. Its absolutely working.....!! If u can also help me with 1 more thing, it will be of great great help! when it is adding the value to listbox,, it should add unique entries and sorted in ascending order. I have a code for list box unique and sort , bt those 2 r seperate codes where first write data to listbox then sort then uniq, but i dont want it that way coz i have 10,000 + rows . As and when it adds value to list box i want it to add unique values and in sorted order. Could anyone plzzzz help me ... for the same above code..

Comment: karma , Thank u so much for ur response as well..... that also works.!

Comment: Hi @CDP1802 ..ur help is really priceless , i really dont have words to express my thanks to u.. Thank u veryyy much!!!